# Send email through php using mailer class get spam emails

Tags: php, email

I am working to send email via the PHP Mailer class. I tried many times but I'm getting spam email every time. I want to use it for [whatuser](http://whatuser.com). I am using the PHP Mailer class and get spam emails. Please help, my code is the following:

```
require_once("PHPMailer-final/class.phpmailer.php");
$admin_email="support@example.com";

$admin_email_caption="example.com";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host     = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP servers
$mail->Port = 26;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->Username = "support@example.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "123456789"; // SMTP password
$subject=$subject_mem;
$cs_email=$to_mem;
$body_admin = $body_mem;
$headers ="From:".$admin_email_caption."<".$admin_email.">\nReply-To:".$admin_email."\nContent-Type:text/html";
$mail->From = $admin_email;
$mail->FromName = $admin_email_caption;
$mail->AddReplyTo($admin_email);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body_admin;
$mail->AltBody = "This is alt body.";
$mail->AddAddress($cs_email);
if(!$mail->Send())
    @mail($cs_email,$subject,$body_admin,$headers) or die("not send");
//echo $cs_email."<br>";
$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
$mail=NULL;
```

Comment: Why you are using `mail()` function, When using `PHPMailer` ?

Comment: What do you mean, "I get spam email"? Are you spamming yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should check your **SMTP** configurations.

Maybe `SMTP` configuration is not correct. For this reason your `mail()` function is working. And `mail()` function have some missing `headers`. Example `charset`. Missing or invalid header is another reason for getting mail in `spam`

Here is the details about [PHPMailer Configurations](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Uncomment the line `//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` for Debugging your SMTP configurations